# Allow visitors to view private posts in Wordpress using a token

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

Is it possible to allow visitors (anyone) to view private posts on my Wordpress site using a token? So a visitor with a valid token will be able to view my private posts. The token will be generated from my web-app. How to achieve this?

Comment: I found a similar question that has a good explanation here to maybe get you started.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470417/wordpress-api-get-posts-from-private-wordpress-com-site

Comment: will check that out. thanks Zac